# Storing settings in session to be used later

Tags: php, ajax, session

I am storing various settings in a object of class and then saving that settings in session as I need to use this settings in subsequent ajax calls.

Most of the time (I would say 90%), it works properly, but many times it doesn't store settings in session and ajax call gets failed.

This is my class code

```
    Class PDOSoup {

    private $tableName;
    private $columns;
    private $currentpage;
    private $limit;
    private $objKey;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->objKey = $this->getRandomKey();
    }

    public function setTableName($param) {
        $tableName = $param;
    }

    public function setCurrentPage($param) {
        $currentpage = $param;
    }


    public function setLimit($param) {
        $limit = $param;
    }

    public function saveObject() {
       $_SESSION[$this->objKey] = serialize($this);
    }
}
```

This is my ajax call

```
    //this key is stored in the input type hidden to access object again
$instanceKey = $_REQUEST["object_key"];
$obj = unserialize($_SESSION[$instanceKey]);//here it gives error sometimes
//now call method of class
$obj->someothermethod();
```

this $obj->someothermethod(); works most of the time but some times it fails and
gives error that on the session line

```
Notice: Undefined index: !KpcZ6nkAr in
```

can somebody explain why sometimes it doesn't work? Or is there better way 
to do same thing?

Comment: Is the interval of the failure regular or irregular?

Comment: Where does $_REQUEST["object_key"] come from? GET? POST? SESSION? COOKIE? Try to figure out when and why it is not set

Comment: After session save, I get this object key and store on that page in input type="hidden" name="object_key" and during ajax request I pass this.